# Add a factor column to quantmod/xts

Tags: r, xts, quantmod, r-factor

what am i doing wrong here?

```
library(quantmod)
getSymbols('^GSPC')
b <- tail(GSPC, 20) #for brevity
is.factor(factor(Cl(b), labels=c('A')))
> TRUE
b$f <- factor(Cl(b), labels=c('A'))
is.factor(b$f)
[1] FALSE
```

I would like a column in my xts/quantmod object to be a factor. I have no idea why it is not working.

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It doesn't work because xts/zoo objects are a matrix with an index attribute and you can't mix types in a matrix.  `GSPC` contains numeric data, so you can only add numeric columns.

Comment: Oh, uh, hmm. Thanks for the quick reply. I would like to do some work with categorical data, all I really need is the dates so I can line up the results, whats the best way to get them from the xts/zoo object?

Comment: @dizzy: "matrix with an index attribute", so see `?index`.